# Visual Studio 2019 repeatedly showing window prompt to Sign In

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise with latest Version . Recently I am getting window prompt frequently, How to get rid of this?

I tried to sign out and sign in under account settings of Visual studio but in vain.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what's your VS version? Please go to Help-About Microsoft Visual Studio and check the detail version number and share it. Meanwhile, you can try to enable “System web browser” under Tools > Options > Environment > Accounts > Add and reauthenticate accounts using: dropdown. Then, sign in your accounts again.

Comment: I have the same issue and am currently looking for a resolution.  It only occurs with a single solution that I am using. All other solutions are fine. Because of this I am guessing it is something to do with a specific project configuration.  I heard it may be packages stored in Azure?  I am trying to review/locate something now

Comment: I have project related Custom NuGet package sources , I remove all those --> logout from account then logged in. Its worked for me.  ```Project-->Manage Nuget Packages--> Click on Package Source Settings (Right Side Top Corner) ```